# How to compile an .app bundle for OSX

Tags: java, ant, javafx-2

I need to create a .app file in order to use my javafx application on osx.

I already read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm), but it doesn't help much...

The tutorial above has a topic "DMG Package" but when I compile my app with the fxbuild there is no .app folder/conainer anywhere(also no dmg). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 2022**

Parts of this answer are obsolete.

The `javafxpackager` tool has been removed from the jdk and replaced with the `jpackage` tool.

If you wish to accomplish a similar task today, I encourage you to use the `joackage` tool either by:

1. Executing jpackage directly from the command line or a shell script similarly to, but different from, this answer, OR
2. Executing joackage from a maven or grade build tool plugin, for example:

   - the “badass jlink plugin” for gradle OR
   - the [Akmsn
     jpackage-maven-plugin](https://github.com/Akman/jpackage-maven-plugin).

**Sample Build Script**

Here is a [script](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/5018976) which creates and installs a .app bundle on OS X.

```sh
#! /bin/bash
 
################
# package.sh
#
# Packages java code as a native OS X application
#
# - Fetches source for a Java Swing HelloWorld application from the web
# - Compiles the source
# - Packages the source into a native Mac application
# - Installs the native Mac application
# - Runs the native Mac Application
#
# Requires:
#   OS X 10.8+
#   Java 8b77+ (http://jdk8.java.net/download.html) 
#   super user rights on the execution account
#
# To Use:
#   chmod +x package.sh
#   ./package.sh
# As the script executes sudo commands, enter your 
# superuser password as needed.
################
 
 
# select java version
set JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version
 
# cleanup work directory and any existing application install
if [ -d work ]; then
  rm -rf work
fi
 
if [ -d /Applications/HelloWorld.app ]; then
  sudo rm -rf /Applications/HelloWorld.app
fi
 
# create work directory and use it
mkdir work
cd work
 
# fetch a simple HelloWorldSwing sample java source from the web
mkdir start
cd start
curl -O http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/start/HelloWorldSwingProject/src/start/HelloWorldSwing.java
cd ..
 
# compile the HelloWorldSwing java source
$JAVA_HOME/bin/javac start/HelloWorldSwing.java
 
# create a jar file 
$JAVA_HOME/bin/jar cvf HelloWorldSwing.jar start/*.class
 
# make an executable jar file
$JAVA_HOME/bin/javafxpackager -createjar -srcdir . -appclass start.HelloWorldSwing -srcfiles HelloWorldSwing.jar -noembedlauncher -outdir . -outfile HelloWorld.jar
 
# package the jar and java runtime as a native application with installer
$JAVA_HOME/bin/javafxpackager -deploy -srcdir . -srcfiles HelloWorld.jar -outdir . -outfile HelloWorld -appclass start.HelloWorldSwing -native -name HelloWorld
 
# codesign the application using your apple developer ID (if you have one)
# allows the app to be accepted by the Apple GateKeeper - https://developer.apple.com/resources/developer-id/
# codesign -s "Developer ID Application" bundles/HelloWorld.app
 
# mount the installer disk image
hdiutil attach bundles/HelloWorld.dmg
 
# install the HelloWorld application from the disk image
sudo cp -R /Volumes/HelloWorld/HelloWorld.app /Applications
 
# unmount the installer disk image
umount `mount | grep HelloWorld | cut -d " " -f1`
 
# leave the work directory
cd ..
 
# run our newly installed application
open -a HelloWorld
```

**Answers to additional questions**

> is there no way to create one on windows?

If you want to create a Mac App, you need a Mac (at least for JavaFX 2.2 or 8 apps).

> WAIT- is this only Java 8?? "Requires: Java 8b77+"

The script might also work with later versions of Java 7 (e.g. after build 6), but I have never tried it with those versions.

It definitely won't work with early versions of Java 7 (e.g. before build 6) nor any version of Java previous to that.

> "Requires: OS X 10.8+"

The script might also work on OS X 10.7, but I haven't tested with that version.

It definitely won't work on 10.6 or earlier (and neither would the app produced).

> tried a java class called app-bundler.jar but that didnt work

I've never tried app-bundler.jar and cannot comment on what it may or may not do.  This solution does not relate to app-bundler.jar.

Comment: is there no way to create one on windows?

Comment: i tried a java class called app-bundler.jar but that didnt work :(

Comment: WAIT- is this only Java 8?? "Requires: Java 8b77+"

Comment: Edited answer to address additional questions.